# Merging Every Other Row Excel

Tags: excel

I have data in the below format where the first two columns are categories and the rest are data:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| AAA | xxxx | 4 | 5 | 6 |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| AAA | yyyy | 4 | 5 | 6 |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| BBB | xxxx | 2 | 3 | 9 |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| BBB | yyyy | 3 | 3 | 3 |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
...
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| NNN | xxxx | 7 | 4 | 4 |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| NNN | yyyy | 7 | 4 | 4 |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I want to merge each set of of cells of the first column to make the data appear neater. There will always be Two lines in a Set (Category and two subb categories:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|     | xxxx | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| AAA |+++++++++++++++++++
|     | yyyy | 4 | 5 | 6 |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|     | xxxx | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| BBB |+++++++++++++++++++
|     | yyyy | 4 | 5 | 6 |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
...
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|     | xxxx | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| NNN |+++++++++++++++++++
|     | yyyy | 4 | 5 | 6 |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: Can you be more specific with the actual question here? It's unclear how this is a programming question.

Comment: You can look into PivotTable or PowerPivot. Another option is VBA macro

Comment: Unless there is a feature to do this, would require a VBA script to achieve the merge. Basically need a script that merges every two rows of a single column in an excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved:

1. Merge Two Cells Manually
2. Highlight Merged Cell and [Home > Clipboard > Format Painter]
3. Drag over remaining cells in column to duplicate format option